# MySQL how to do an if exist increment in a single query

Tags: sql, mysql

I just wish to have a table to store a number of events by day.

Given a table:

```
create table totals (
    entryday date,
    total int(11) default 0 not null,
    primary key (entryday) );
```

How can I write a simple query which increments, but creates an necessary?

I tried this - but it is not incrementing (it remains at 1):

```
REPLACE totals SET total = total + 1, entryday = "08-01-11"
```

Obviously this could be done in 2 queries quite simply, but it's through JDBC calls and may be called many times, so 1 query would be better.

Comment: could you post the results that you want to obtain?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You probably want [`ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO totals (entryday, total)
VALUES ("08-01-11", 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = total + 1
```

That'll set the "08-01-11" `total` to 1 if a row doesn't already exist for that date and increment the `total` by 1 if it does.

Comment: Thanks, that's just the ticket!

Answer (score 3):

For MySQL 5.0+, see [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

```
INSERT INTO totals (entryday, total) VALUES ("08-01-11", 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total=total+1;
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but maybe this query is your answer :

```
update totals set total = total + 1 where entryday = "08-01-11"
```