# Mysql Unique Column - Add one to count

Tags: mysql, count, unique

I have a table, that stores words, there are tree columns id,word and count, word is unique key.

I just want to add +1 to count if word is already insterted. I couldnt find any sql statements,(i might not know what to search on google)

I want to add +1 to count column when i am inserting new data to word. I am not sure about it requires an unique column for this operation.

Can you help me guys?
Regards!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728325/mysql-how-to-do-an-if-exist-increment-in-a-single-query

This is what you want I think. Use ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: Can you give an example of desired output from a particular query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tablename (word, count)
VALUES ("TheWord", 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1
```

I believe this is what you are looking for. Is there any reason to have the id column if word is unique?